# accessing database between same instance of a micro service

Tags: microservices

In my project, I have a microservice [say A] and it has a SQL database. We have a 5 node cluster and each of the node this microservice runs. So, We have 5 instances running of service A on the cluster. Now, suppose there is a select query in a particular function of the microservice that is retrieving data from the database. Now, since 5 instance are running, all the 5 instance will use the same query and will work on the same data. Is there any way, in which, we can divide data among 5 instances of service A.

Comment: wht you trying to achieve by dividing data??

Answer (score 0):

Application clustering is different to database clustering. You cannot "divide" data among the 5 instances of application services since all application instances require a similar set of data to function (unless your application is designed to work on a subset of the data, i.e. each application instance is used to serve a specific list of countries, then you might be able to break the data up by country).

You can look into clustering at the database level for ideas on how you can cluster at the SQL level: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2012/02/introduction-sql-server-clusters/ .